# How can I read data from this XML in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-4.5

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.virtualbox.org/" version="1.12-windows">
  <Global>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/GroupDefinitions/" value="m=254e0435-0f3f-445b-a35d-1f6d774a0fc3"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastItemSelected" value="m=from_diag"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastWindowPosition" value="255,217,770,550"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RecentFolderHD" value="//diag03-pc/vbox_hdd"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RecentListHD" value="\\diag03-pc\vbox_hdd\xp_legacy_mode.vdi"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/SplitterSizes" value="255,510"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/Toolbar/MachineTools/Order" value="None"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/UpdateCheckCount" value="3"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/UpdateDate" value="1 d, 2017-10-23, stable, 5.2.0"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <MachineRegistry>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{254e0435-0f3f-445b-a35d-1f6d774a0fc3}" src="C:\Users\bogna\VirtualBox VMs\from_diag\from_diag.vbox"/>
    </MachineRegistry>
    <NetserviceRegistry>
      <DHCPServers>
        <DHCPServer networkName="HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" IPAddress="192.168.56.100" networkMask="255.255.255.0" lowerIP="192.168.56.101" upperIP="192.168.56.254" enabled="1"/>
      </DHCPServers>
    </NetserviceRegistry>
    <SystemProperties defaultMachineFolder="C:\Users\bogna\VirtualBox VMs" defaultHardDiskFormat="VDI" VRDEAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" webServiceAuthLibrary="VBoxAuth" LogHistoryCount="3" exclusiveHwVirt="false"/>
    <USBDeviceFilters/>
  </Global>
</VirtualBox>
```

How can I Get the uuid and src from MachineEntrys from this xml to an array?
.net 4.5

I tried it, becouse the array was empty:

** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.

```
        void getfromxml()
        {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(vboxxml);


            XmlNodeList nodes  = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/VirtualBox/Global/MachineRegistry/MachineEntry");

            int i = 0;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                machines[i,0] = node.Attributes["uuid"].Value;
                machines[i,1] = node.Attributes["src"].Value;

                i++;
            }



        }
```

Comment: You might also consider using the `XDocument` class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are ignoring the XML namespaces. You might try:

```
XmlNodeList nodes  = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='MachineEntry']");
```

(expand other levels using he local-name() function if needed)